# Gnome-terminal and Xfce4-terminal with ISO-encoding needs special-character keys to be pressed twice

Tags: gnome-terminal, encoding, special-characters, utf-8, xfce4-terminal

In a gnome-terminal as well as in a xfce4-terminal, when I change its character-encoding from standard UTF-8 (with 2 bytes for special-characters) to ISO-Latin 8859-15 (always 1 byte), the following happens:

While outputting of ISO-Latin encoded text works fine, for example:

```
cat textfile-iso-latin.txt
```

However input isn't working as expected. When I enter a special character (like Umlaut, Sonderzeichen, äöü) with the keyboard in the very same terminal, I need to hit the key on the keyboard twice in order to make it display.

Is the keyboard still in UTF-8 mode where such special characters take two bytes? How would I change this behaviour in order to make this hiccup disappear?

Thanks.

Comment: What utility do you type these characters into? E.g. your shell, bash? You need to update the locale settings (LANG and/or LC_* env variables) so that bash is informed about the new encoding. "Is the keyboard still in UTF-8 mode[...]?" – No, the input and output encodings are always the same, try typing into e.g. `od -t x1` to make sure.

Comment: Thanks Egmont for your reply.

I'm using a bash shell, and indeed the LANG was set to "de_DE.UTF-8", so being different from the terminal's encoding ISO-8859-15.

However, since I don't want to install de_DE.ISO-LATIN-8859-15 system-wide (since the "locale" command says it's not installed) but just use the ISO-Latin encoding for the terminal of one user, I found the workaround with the "luit" command to be the easiest solution. Please see the exact description below in my new reply.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get ISO-Latin encoded input and output in my bash shell running in a full UTF-8 environment (as usual with Ubuntu) is to use the workaround which has been mentioned in a related but not identical question here: "[Switch encoding of terminal with a command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87227/switch-encoding-of-terminal-with-a-command)"

When in my UTF-8 xfce-terminal or gnome-terminal I run my old ISO-Latin encoded programs like this:

```
luit -encoding iso-8859-15 gawk -f script.awk
```

… then the luit tool converts the ISO-Latin encoded input and output of my program (an Awk script in that case) to the UTF-8 encoded terminal.

This workaround works fine (so far).